# Can't create objects with a required API using Calendar

Tags: java

I am trying to create multiple objects of a train schedule using the required constructor,

```
public Station(String city, Calendar arrival, Calendar departure, int day)
```

However when I create the objects I can't pass the arrival and departure times because 20:30 etc is considered an int. I would love to just change Calendar to int in the constructor, but apparently it has to be done with Calendar.

```
Station stop1= new  Station("Vancouver",null , 2030, 1)
```

This is want I try to create but like I said it won't take the parameters.

So obviously I need to think outside the box here and start messing around with Calendar but I'm not sure if I should be doing that under the constructor below:

```
 public Station(String city, Calendar arrival, Calendar departure, int day){    
    this.city=city;
    this.arrival=arrival;
    this.departure=departure;
    this.day=day;
}
```

or if I have to create some new method and tie it all together. On my research I came across a method that I altered a bit, but I still can't seem to implement it into my object creation using those parameters of "arrival" and "departure".

```
private static Calendar getCalendar(int hour, int minute) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);         
    return c;
}
```

So I guess I'm wondering if anyone can drop some hints, point me in the right direction of something else maybe I should be looking up online. This is the last and hardest question on my assignment and I can't even get the 10 objects created to start the train schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would love to just change Calendar to int in the constructor, but apparently it has to be done with Calendar.

I am not sure what you mean exactly with this, but lets say for some reason you prefer to keep the constructor as it is now, then what you need to do with the code you already posted is something like this

```
Station stop1= new  Station("Vancouver",null , getCalendar(20, 30) , 1)
```

Otherwise you can do as suggested in the other answers

Comment: Our assignment questions comes with a list of API's to follow and we are supposed to implement them. Apparently we can add to it, but we still have to implement the provided list. Most people on my course are not happy with how the overall course is structured. Thanks for your reply. I will try it out.

Comment: got it, well then this is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I like the **composite** approach.

```
public StationAdapter {

   private readonly Station station;

   public StationAdapter(String city, int arrival, int departure, int day) {
   // Create station 

   }   
}
```

Or eventually a **Builder Pattern**.